# Access data of double pointers array

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc

I'm writing a data structure which uses a static array of double pointers. Each cell of the first array points to a dynamic array of pointers where each one can point to a type of data (let's suppose an `int`). I would like to access the data from the main array of pointers

Here's an ***example*** of what i would like to achieve, *i'm omitting on purpose checks* over the correct allocation of `malloc` in order to make the code clearer :

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef int *pointer;

int main() {
    int **mainArray[10] = {NULL};
    int **p = NULL;
    int n = 5;
    p = malloc(15 * sizeof(pointer));

    //the following instruction makes no sense since the pointer
    //is not initialized, as suggested in the asnwers. 
    *p[3] = n;
    mainArray[4] = p;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how to access to the `int` value from `mainArray`, for example, to print its value.

The idea was to allocate dynamic memory using `p` and then take track of the memory created with `mainArray`.

I know that with `double` pointers I can use for example `**mainArray[n]`, but I found no way on how to specify the index of the second dynamic array. Using `**mainArray[n]` I will access to `mainArray[n]` and then the `int` pointed by `p[0]` (if i'm not wrong).

How do I specify,*for example*, to access to `p[3]` in `mainArray[4]` (maybe in order to print it with a `printf`)?

**PS**: I know that what I'm doing could be easily achieved with a matrix, but I need this approach because of some external constraints.

Comment: This is incorrect. ** already does two dereferences so a double pointer becomes a value. You can’t index that anymore. Also your assignment is wrong since you’re not allocating anything to mainArray etc. If you just put the code you wrote to a compiler it will give errors to start with. And there’s a saying that if you need three star programming (see mainArray) there’s most likely something very wrong with the code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Why am i not allocating anything to mainArray? The idea was to make array in the cell of mainArray pointing to the same address pointed by p, which is the address of the allocated dynamic memory. Am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, you do have 10 pointers in mainArray and you can assign things in it, but **p[3] for example doesn’t work since it’s not a triple pointer, nor do you allocate anything to the second level of it. This is quite complicated and not clear why you need this complexity.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I edited it, is it right now? By the way i need it this way because i have the first static mainArray where (in my real project) each cell points to an hashmap

Comment: You’re still accessing things without assigning with *p[3]. You’ve only allocated 15 pointers, which point wherever they happen to point and then you’re trying to access the memory where the first points. Not allowed

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm so confused, i hope someone will answer and clear my doubts. Seems i have misunderstood a lot of things in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to access to the int value from `mainArray`,
>   for example to print his value.
>
> The idea was to allocate dynamic memory using `p` and then take track of
>   the memory created with `mainArray`.

You do this part correctly, yielding in `p` a pointer to an object that can be reasonably described as a dynamic array of 15 `int *`.  The value of `p` is of the correct type to be assigned to an element of `mainArray`, but note that none of `p`'s elements is initialized.  They do not point to anything.  You need to assign values to those, so that they point somewhere, before you can access the locations to which they point.

> I know that with double pointers i can use for example `**mainArray[n]`,
>   but i found no way on how to specify the index of the second dynamic
>   array. Using `**mainArray[n]` i will access to `mainArray[n]` and then the
>   int pointed by `p[0]` (if i'm not wrong).
>
> How do i specify (for example) to access to `p[3]` in `mainArray[4]`
>   (maybe in order to print it with a printf)?

`mainArray[4]` is an `int **`.  If we assigned it to your variable `p`, then we could access the element at index 3 via the ordinary indexing operator, as you show.  The same applies, then, to the expression `mainArray[4]`: the expression `mainArray[4][3]` gives you the value you want (an `int *`).

You do, in general, need to be careful about operator associativity and precedence when chaining operators together, but this specific case is simple.  You *could* write the same thing as `(mainArray[4])[3]`, but I don't see why you would want to do.

Perhaps the thing you're struggling with is that in `mainArray[4][3]`, the two indexing operators are separate and independent.  You don't need `mainArray` to be declared as a two-dimensional array to use that form; you just need it to be declared as a pointer to or array of pointers or arrays (a two-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays).  The first indexing operator applies to `mainArray` itself; the second applies to the result of the first.  This is not too unlike the evaluation of `1 + 2 + 3`, in that there, the result of the first `+` operation is an operand of the second.

Comment: Got it! I understood what was the problem, your explanation was clear and very on point. Anyway, I'm asking this because I'm creating an array of hashmaps. This was a easier case of my real problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all - do not typedef pointers as code using it is very difficult to read and error prone.

Your first malloc allocates only memory for the pointers to the `int`s

To store the actual objects you need to allocate the memory for this object.

```
p[3] = malloc(sizeof(**p));
*p[3] = n;
```

you can also assign it with the pointer to the existing object;

```
int x;
p[3] = &x;
*p[3] = n;
```

you can also allocate memory for more than one object

```
p[3] = malloc(100 * sizeof(**p));
*(p[3] + 10) = n;
p[3][9] = n;
```

You can access it via the array of pointers to pointers but we are getting into the three star dilemma. To threestar or not to threestar. IMO when you get to the point where ***pointers (or ** arrays) are needed, you need to seriously reconsider your algorithm.

http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: This is correct and useful information, but it is all tangential to the question that was actually posed.

Comment: Upvoted, it helped me to understand the error in *p[3]=n, that in my code makes no sense since i've never allocated anything to that pointer.

Comment: Anyway, i'm creating an array of hashmaps, is it a crazy thing?

Comment: This the question you need answer yourself.